# Issue in saving file

Tags: c

I'm trying to save the socket message according to bellow code but it's not creating file or saving socket message:

```
//Create socket
int mySock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (mySock<0) {
    printf("Error creatig socket\n");
exit(1);
} 

//connect socket to server
if(connect(mySock,(struct sockaddr*)&sAddress, sizeof(sAddress) ) != 0){
printf("Error in connecting socket\n");
exit(1);
}   

//Send some data:

char message[1024];
sprintf(message, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", pcPage, pcWWWServer);
    if (send(mySock, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Sent\n"); 
    }

//Receive some data:
char recBuffer[16000];
    if (recv(mySock,recBuffer, sizeof(recBuffer),0) > 0){
printf("%s\n", recBuffer);
}


//Save it to disk
FILE *fp = fopen (write, "output.txt");{
//for (sizeof(recBuffer), 0) > 0;{
    fprintf (fp, recBuffer, write);
    fclose(fp);
}        
close(mySock);
return 0;
}
```

}

I believe there an issue in saving file can someone help

Comment: What is `write`? and did you read the documentation for [`fopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)?

Comment: *"there an issue in saving file "* - more like there is an issue in even *opening* the file, which (a) you're doing wrong, and (b) goes completely unchecked for any error, as you march on, assuming the open succeeded, and the file is ready for writing (which it isn't). It would seem `fopen("output.txt", "w")` would be more in alignment with what you need, and even then *check your IO operations*, including opens and closes, for failure states.

Comment: Yeah, the `fprintf` needs a format string. I guess you wanted to use fwrite, instead.

Comment: I changed fprintf to:     FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("/usr/home/student/socet_prog/output.txt", "w");
    printf("%s\n", recBuffer);
    fputs (recBuffer, fp); 
    fclose(fp);      still nothing is saving to file

Comment: Would it be better if I add a loop "while" , "for" or can i do it without them ?

Comment: To anyone wondering it worked.     fptr = fopen("output1.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", recBuffer);
    fputs (recBuffer, fptr); 
    fclose(fptr);